# Multiple insert in one Query Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, foreign-keys, one-to-one

I have this two tables a User Table and the Attendance table, Here is what I want to do:
While inserting a User on the User table, the Attendance table will also be updated (the user_id of the User Table will be Inserted to the Attendance Table as a foreign key), the Primary key of my User table is Auto Increment, that's why I can't insert it manually to the Attendance Table, what should I do? Is there any cheat in laravel that can do this easily?

Here is my Controller for Register

```
    public function register()
    {
        $myemployee=Employee::all();
        return View::make('registration',compact('myemployee'));
    }

    public function registerEmp()
    {
        $input = Input::all();


        $command = new Employee;
        $command->firstname=$input['firstname'];
        $command->lastname=$input['lastname'];
        $command->position=$input['position'];
        $command->save();

        return Redirect::action('EmployeesController@register');


    }
```

Here is my Migration

```
         public function up()
         {
            Schema::create('employees',function($table)
            {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->text('firstname');
                $table->text('lastname');
                $table->text('position');
                $table->timestamps();

            });

                public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('attendances', function(Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('employees');
                $table->timestamp('intime');
                $table->timestamp('offtime');
            });
        }
```

Employee.php file

```
          <?php

            class Employee extends Eloquent
            {

            }



            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last inserted ID in users table by assigning the return value of User::create(), which is a static Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, to a variable, then use that variable to insert user_id in your attendances table.

Here is an example:

```
public function registerEmp() {
    $input = Input::all();

    // Create an employee.
    $employee = Employee::create($input);

    // Create an attendance entry as well.
    Attendance::create([
        'user_id'=>$employee->id,
        // other columns...
    ]);

    return Redirect::action('EmployeesController@register');}
```

Comment: I'm still reading it, takes me time to understand. Newbie here. Sorry, but i will make it through, just need time. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to laravel

Comment: oh, so this codes will be inerted at the model's file?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really really not a smart guy. I just want to know where to execute the above codes

Comment: No, use it in your controller. I meant that if your models extend Eloquent, create() is available.

Comment: yes it extends eloquents, please help me, can you update your answer and use my code. Thanks

Comment: @jakebalba Check it out.

Comment: I'm getting this error sir: 'Cannot redeclare class Employee'

Comment: Could you show your Employee.php and relevant controller file?

Comment: figured out the last problem, now i got this error 'Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ MassAssignmentException'

Comment: I was just wrong earlier on the naming of my model, both model has the same class, the attendance class has the same class as the employee, I have changed it and the first error is gone

Comment: Define either a $fillable or $guarded property for mass assignment. See the document http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Sir thank you, readed it all up and it works, but now i have an error again iahave this. 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`thor`.`attendances`, CONSTRAINT `attendances_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)' I suspect maybe this is beacause of the foreign keys and primary keys?

Comment: Yeah, make sure that you successfully insert an employee then insert an attendance entry.